# How to use flow-typed to type Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, flowtype

I'm trying to type Redux correctlly with flow-typed.
I use the `Store` import from `redux` to type my store like this, Flow uses the `flow-typed` file `redux_v4.x.x.js` and raises me an error:

```
/* @flow */
import rootReducer from '@reducers/index'
import type { Store } from 'redux'
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const configureStore = () => {
   const store: Store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
  )
  return store
}

export { configureStore as default }
```

With this code, I obtain the following error: `Cannot use Store [1] without 2-3 type arguments`.

I've tried to define it like this too `const store: Store<S, A>` but then Flow complains that he doesn't find the declaration for S and A, that seems normal.

In the `redux_v4.x.x.js` file used by `flow-typed`, Store is defined like this:

```
  declare export type Store<S, A, D = Dispatch<A>> = {
    // rewrite MiddlewareAPI members in order to get nicer error messages (intersections produce long messages)
    dispatch: D,
    getState(): S,
    subscribe(listener: () => void): () => void,
    replaceReducer(nextReducer: Reducer<S, A>): void,
  };
```

I've already seen this post which is quite similar to mine but has no answer so far, so this post is like a bump [typing redux store using flowtype and flow-typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702834/typing-redux-store-using-flowtype-and-flow-typed).

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide `S` and `A` to the `Store` type. For example,

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import type { Store } from 'redux';

type State = Array<number>;
type Action = { type: 'A' };
type MyStore = Store<State, Action>;
const store: MyStore = createStore(...);

// or inline
const store: Store<Array<number>, { type: 'A' }> = createStore(...);
```

Check out the example provided in [`test_createStore.js`](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/redux_v4.x.x/flow_v0.89.x-/test_createStore.js) or, for a more complete example, check out [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos-flow).